# Making Jest wait for a React component's HTML to change before taking snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm currently snapshot testing a React component that fetches some data from an API and displays a loading screen until the data is fetched. My test currently looks like this:

```
jest.mock("../../../utils/utils/APIWrapper")

it('matches the snapshot', () => {
    const tree = renderer
        .create(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <LocationSummary
                    {...locationSummaryProps}
                />
            </BrowserRouter>
        )


    expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

This test passes, but looking at the snapshot file shows that the snapshot taken is of the loading screen rather than the loaded app. How can I make Jest wait until the loading screen is gone(either through programmatically waiting until the component's state is no longer changing or through waiting until certain HTML elements are gone) before taking the snapshot?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make test async and wrap render inside act

```
jest.mock("../../../utils/utils/APIWrapper")

it('matches the snapshot', async () => {

    let tree;

    await act(() => {
      tree = renderer
        .create(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <LocationSummary
                    {...locationSummaryProps}
                />
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    });

    expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Comment: This answer solves the issues - unfortunately it is nor marked as accepted but should be!